# Unable to install yarn packages via docker build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yarn-lock.json

I'm trying to speed up spinning up docker by having all current packages in yarn.lock be installed on the image already. I think I'm doing yarn install incorrectly, that it is working somewhere else?

relevant part of dockerfile:

```
# Create a dir
WORKDIR /(WORKDIR)
# Time to install all our dependencies
COPY package.json /(WORKDIR)/package.json
COPY yarn.lock /(WORKDIR)/yarn.lock

# Need the executables to be in the path
ENV PATH /(WORKDIR)/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
RUN yarn check --verify-tree || yarn install --frozen-lockfile
```

I think my last line is incorrect. It is installing somewhere, but not on the package itself? Either that or caching might be an issue. If I start the image I find the output of `yarn check --verify-tree` is still the current state of the image.

Comment: How are you running the image, and what are you seeing when you look around?

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to `yarn install` during my Docker build. I was getting networking errors (`getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN`):

```
Step 6/8 : COPY yarn.lock /app/yarn.lock
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e55488a3d051
Step 7/8 : RUN yarn
 ---> Running in 5bb8d663d00b
yarn install v1.22.15
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/app-root-path/-/app-root-path-3.0.0.tgz: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.yarnpkg.com".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/app/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
ERROR: Service 'web-svc' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c yarn' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I recently updated my Ubuntu Linux system, and figured that might be the cause. So, I restarted the `docker.service` and that resolved the issue.

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `RUN yarn` and make sure `COPY` code base after `yarn`.

```
FROM        node:12.14.0-alpine3.11

ENV         NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR     /app

COPY        package.json ./
COPY        yarn.lock ./
RUN         yarn

COPY        src ./
```

I test it in my machine, you can see if I change `yarn.lock`. And if I don't change my `yarn.lock`

```
$ docker build -t demo .
Step 1/6 : FROM        node:12.14.0-alpine3.11
 ---> 1cbcaddb8074
Step 2/6 : ENV         NODE_ENV=production
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dc7f1a2f7d90
Step 3/6 : WORKDIR     /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eec9363713a5
Step 4/6 : COPY        package.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fde6cf7bb577
Step 5/6 : COPY        yarn.lock ./
 ---> 6a1369622d79
Step 6/6 : RUN         yarn
 ---> Running in ff6433969bea
yarn install v1.21.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning sha.js@2.4.11: Invalid bin entry for "sha.js" (in "sha.js").
warning url-loader@1.1.2: Invalid bin field for "url-loader".
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > styled-components@5.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-is@>= 16.8.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 35.97s.
Removing intermediate container ff6433969bea
 ---> 8dcd2124289d
Successfully built 8dcd2124289d

$docker build -t demo .
Step 1/6 : FROM        node:12.14.0-alpine3.11
 ---> 1cbcaddb8074
Step 2/6 : ENV         NODE_ENV=production
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dc7f1a2f7d90
Step 3/6 : WORKDIR     /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eec9363713a5
Step 4/6 : COPY        package.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fde6cf7bb577
Step 5/6 : COPY        yarn.lock ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6a1369622d79
Step 6/6 : RUN         yarn
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8dcd2124289d
Step 7/7 : COPY        src ./
 ---> 13474b882e11
```

Comment: oops that was a typo.

Comment: so when using COPY is there a difference between using src or . ?
I'm not seeing a clear answer on the docker documentation

Comment: It's ok to COPY . or src. The point is if you COPY all code before installing libraries it's don't cached.

Comment: Because you mentioned it's part of Dockerfile, I guess you COPY code base before yarn install.